Distribution of the longest queue's length in parallel queues
Considering $n$ people line up at $q$ queues.
Let's say all people choose which queue to line up randomly, so each people has probability $1/q$ to choose a particular queue. Then the length of any particular queue is a Binomial distribution $B(n, 1/q)$.
Now, what is the the distribution of the longest queue of all $q$ queues?
Specifically, if $q=2$, what would be the result?
Recall when $n$ is large, Binomial distribution $B(n, 1/q)$ becomes like a normal distribution, then if $q=n$, and $n$ is large, is there a similar approximation of the longest queue?
Side note: I ask this question as I ran into a computer algorithm question, for those familiar with Hash table, hashing function, mapping a key to a hash value, is just as a people line up to a queue. In the algorithm question, for a particular $j\in \{0,1,\cdots, n-1\}$, $L_j$ denotes the length of the $j$-th queue, and $W$ denotes the worst queue, i.e. the longest queue. The algorithm questions asks to prove $P(L_j > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}) \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $P(W > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}) \le \frac{1}{n}$.
While $P(L_j > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}) \le \frac{1}{n^2}$ can be proved with the Cernoff bound, from it I couldn't find a clean way to $P(W > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}) \le \frac{1}{n}$.
At first glance this is easy:
$$P\left(W > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right) = 1 - P\left(W \le \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right)  = 1 - \left[P\left(L_j \le \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right) \right]^n = 1 - \left[1-P\left(L_j > \frac{4\ln n}{\ln \ln n}\right) \right]^n < 1 - \left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}  \right)^n < \frac1n $$
However, there is a gap -- different queues are actually interfering with each other, for example, with a big $n$, $P(L_j =0)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\approx \frac1e$, but $P(W=0)=0$, we don't have $P(W=0)=P^n(L_j=0)$. Hence I'm raising the question as the content.

Let $L=(L_1,\ldots, L_q)$ denote the vector of queue lengths. Then, the key to solve your problem is to observe that $L$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $$n,p_1= \frac 1 q, \dots, p_q=\frac 1 q.$$ Fortunately,  under the hypothesis of equiprobability, which is the case in your question, nice asymptotic distributional properties of $$M=\max\{L_1,\ldots, L_q\}$$ has been studied in this paper Tail Probabilities and Percentiles of the Multinomial Maximum; summarized  in this answer. Also, exact algorithms to compute the distribution of $M$ are presented and compared with approximate ones in this paper Exact Algorithms for the Multinomial Counts based on exact results given by Rappeport (1968) and Corrado (2011).
Now you can simply use existing results on the distribution of $M$, given in the above references; I am not going to reproduce them here.

thank you for the explanation!

@athos You are welcome!

If you've already got $$P\left (L_j>\frac{4\ln n}{\ln\ln n}\right )\leq 1/n^2,$$ which was the hard part, then
$$P(W>x)\leq \sum_jP(L_j>x),$$ as for any $x$ we have $$\{W>x\}=\bigcup_j\{L_j>x\}.$$

Indeed! Using adding up is much easier than using multiplication as no need to worry about whether events are independent. Any idea, pls, on the distribution of $P(W>x)$, besides the upper limit?

@athos your bound is tight up to the constant. The distribution of $L_j$ is approximately Poisson(1), and so the probability that $L_j\geq k$ is at least $e^{-1}/k!$. For $k=c\log n/\log\log n$ and $c$ sufficiently small, this is bigger than $1/\sqrt{n}$. It is possible to show that treating these as independent events is not too far off from being correct, so with high probability $W=\Theta(\log n/\log\log n)$.
